# Incompatible types: LinearLayout cannot be converted to LayoutManager

Tags: android

Here is my code below. I am getting errors in compilation. I am getting the errors below which I think is coming from the linear layout type used. I could not find the ANDROIDX import type. I could not get it working yet. Please help!

> error: cannot find symbol variable sender_messsage_text error: cannot
>   find symbol variable receiver_message_text error: cannot find symbol
>   variable message_receiver_image_view error: cannot find symbol
>   variable custom_messages_layout error: cannot find symbol variable
>   sender_messages_layout

-------------------------  My code below

```
 package com.tom.air;


    import android.graphics.Color;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.recyclerview.R;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.util.List;

    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

    public class MessageAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>
    {
        private List<Messages> userMessagesList;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private DatabaseReference usersRef;


        public MessageAdapter (List<Messages> userMessagesList)
        {
            this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
        }



        public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public TextView senderMessageText, receiverMessageText;
            public CircleImageView receiverProfileImage;
            public ImageView messageSenderPicture, messageReceiverPicture;


            public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);

                senderMessageText = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_messsage_text);
                receiverMessageText = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_message_text);
                receiverProfileImage = (CircleImageView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_image);
                messageReceiverPicture = 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_receiver_image_view);
                messageSenderPicture = 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_sender_image_view);
            }
        }




        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_messages_layout, viewGroup, false);

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            return new MessageViewHolder(view);
        }



        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder 
    messageViewHolder, int i)
        {
            String messageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            Messages messages = userMessagesList.get(i);

            String fromUserID = messages.getFrom();
            String fromMessageType = messages.getType();

            usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fromUserID);

            usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                    {
                        String receiverImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();



 Picasso.get().load(receiverImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });





            messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            if (fromMessageType.equals("text"))
            {
                if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId))
                {

    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages_layout);

    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage() + "\n \n" + messages.getTime() + " - " + messages.getDate());
                }
                else
                {

    messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


 messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messages_layout);

    messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage() + "\n \n" + messages.getTime() + " - " + messages.getDate());
                }
            }
        }




        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return userMessagesList.size();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you added a LayoutManager to your RecyclerView ?

Comment: Yes, I added this  -   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

Comment: I also added this:   import android.widget.LinearLayout;   I could not find the androidx version of it.

Comment: I mean setting a LayoutManager directly to your RecyclerView `recylcerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager())` or something like that.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that. I am new to this. The errors I am getting is (error: cannot find symbol variable sender_messsage_text) as seen in the code posted.

Comment: Can you post your item layout and the class where you instantiate the adapter ?

Comment: Honestly  don't know. kindly explain a bit better

Comment: I finally was able to get rid of the errors by removing one of the import dependencies  RecyclerView R. Thanks to everyone who help on ths